# passing data between snippets

Tags: forms, lift

I have 2 snippets: TakeIn and SendOut.
TakeIn takes data from a search for (1 text field submitted via submit button
and read from RequestVar. Based on this input I am creating and populating
a data structure. I want to display this data structure on the website through
snippet SendOut.

However, I am not sure how to send data between snippets. I tried accessing snippet
variables directly and it did not work. For example in `TakeIn` I am calling
`SendOut.nodeList = this.nodeList;` but this results in a compile time error.

So the question is how does one set data of a snippet from another snippet.
 Or perhaps there is another way to do what I'm trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create a companion object for `SendOut` that contains a `SessionVar`. You could then set that variable directly from the form in `TakeIn` and the `SendOut` snippet will continue to work for the duration of the session.

Alternately, you could try to combine your two snippets into a single [Stateful Snippet](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-4.3.html), with the functionality of each callable through the dispatch method. For example:

```
 class CombinedSnippet extends StatefulSnippet {
   var nodeList = //something

   def dispatch = {
     case "takeIn" => takeInFunctionality()
     case "sendOut" => sendOutFunctionality()
   }
 }
```

Then, reference it in your HTML as `CombinedSnippet.takeIn` or `CombinedSnippet.sendOut`. Not sure what the lifespan of the `StatefulSnippet` is though.